# Is it possible to avoid race conditions without memcache using ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

From what I understand, one of the advantages of ndb over db is the automatic caching. No more writing boring loops to check for hits or misses on a cache and updating/deleting them when an entity is updated. I would like to take advantage of this and not have to deal with memcache anymore, but I don't see how that's possible. Memcache has the huge advantage of CAS, ensuring that I'm not dealing with stale data.

For example, the classic case of incrementing a value. If different requests pull up the entity at the same time, their incremented values are going to be the same. With memcache CAS, this can be avoided.

Is there some way to "check and put" ndb models? If not, shouldn't there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are certainly possible with the datastore. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions) the NDB docs for how to use them.

Comment: Ah, so _that's_ what transactions are for. I read through the docs before but for some reason it didn't penetrate, or maybe I forgot as I didn't need this feature at the time. Thanks!